# javascript/jquery- parsing through all elements of a radio/check box- how to get text value of each element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to parse through a checkbox/radio button.

As an example let us consider the html code for a radio button below--

```
<br/><br/>Lunch-
<input type="radio" name="lunch" value="pasta1" /> Pasta
<input type="radio" name="lunch" value="rissotto1" /> Rissotto
<br/>
```

Now I am using the following code to obtain both the text value shown on screen (eg "Pasta") as well as the value assigned (eg "pasta1")--

```
$(jQuery('input[type="radio"], input[type="checkbox"] ', $(element).parent('form'))).each(function() 
{
                    alert(" Text values =" + $(this).text());
                    alert(" actual values =" + $(this).val());
                                    ---SOME MORE CODE---
}
```

As output, I am not getting any value when I use $(this).text(), although $(this).val() works fine.

How do I get the text values for each element of a radio button/check box... Something that I can use in place of the $(this).text() used above? Is there some other way to obtain the text value (eg "Pasta" or "Risotto" for the example above)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can retrieve the text value with the HTML you have. Ideally you should create label elements to hold the text. e.g.

```
<input type="radio" name="lunch" value="pasta1" /> <label>Pasta</label>
<input type="radio" name="lunch" value="rissotto1" /> <label>Rissotto</label>
```

Then you can get the text:

```
$(this).next().text();
```

EDIT:

If you can't change the HTML, here is a dirty workaround.

Assuming you have a wrapper element (form or div) of id `wrapper` around these radio buttons and each radio button has unique value-

```
/*
 * Create mapping between radio button values and texts
 */ 
var mapping = new Array();
var current_key = '';

$('#wrapper').contents().each(function()
{
   if(current_key)
   {
       mapping[current_key] = $(this).text();
       current_key = '';
   }
   if($(this).attr('type') == 'radio')
   {
       current_key = $(this).val()
   }
});
```

Then you can easily use the mapping:

```
$('input[type=radio]').each(function()
{
    text = mapping[$(this).val()];
})
```

Comment: @Vikk - I dont have any control over the radio button, is there some way to get the text value for the HTML I have specified? Even if you can tell me a way to obtain the HTML code for all the elements of a radio button, then I can parse through those manually...Thanks...

Comment: @Vikk- just one final query, what do I do in case there is one or more specific value(s) repeating across the radio buttons of a form? Thanks...

Comment: In that case, we can make our keys unique by using a combination of name and value e.g. `current_key = $(this).attr('name')+'-'+$(this).val()` something like that. Obviously you'd never have two elements with same name and value

Answer (score 0):

`.text()` is not applicable for those elements who don't have close tag. e.g. `<INPUT> <IMG>` If you read the [documentation of `.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) it is clearly written that *The `.text()` method cannot be used on form inputs or scripts.*

I'm not sure what you exactly wanted to be shown but giving `value` attribute will show a text next to Radio Button. Thats how it works. I'm not sure why you want another extra text after that. But if thats the case then solution suggested by @Vikk is right.