# jquery get the html code for all radios/checkboxes within a form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to parse some elements of a form.

I have with me the form ID/form name.

Now I want to parse through all radio buttons with name= "radio123"(or id="radio123").
But when I try $(this).html on each element (of a radio button)... then I get a blank value...

How do I access the HTML code for all radiobuttons/checkboxes within a form?

Comment: Serialize may help you: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: Already answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061026/javascript-jquery-parsing-through-all-elements-of-a-radio-check-box-how-to-get/8061075 , Please post your comments/doubts there and don't duplicate same question

Comment: @Vikk- Sorry I forgot that I had posted the question there...Will take care in future...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the normal behavior for [jQuery.fn.html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function: `This method uses the browser's innerHTML property.` Look at the examples if you don't understand what I mean.

I don't know why you want to get the HTML (if you want the value, look at the [jQuery.fn.val](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method), but here's a solution

```
$("input:radio").each(function () {
   console.log( this.outerHTML );
});
```

Be careful with the outerHTML, as it is not supported across all browsers you could use this function:

```
function getOuterHTML( node ) {
    var parent = node.parentNode,
        el = document.createElement( parent.tagName ),
        shtml;

    el.appendChild( node );
    shtml = el.innerHTML;
    parent.appendChild( node );

    return shtml;
}
// use it like getOuterHTML( this ) in the preceding each loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work -

```
var htmlarr = [];

$("input[type='radio'][name='radio123'],[type='radio'][id='radio123']").each(function () {
   //any logic you need here
   htmlarr.push($(this).clone().wrap('<div>').parent().html());
})
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/tJ2Zc/

The code uses this method `$(this).clone().wrap('<div>').parent().html()` to get the outer HTML of a DOM element. More info can be found in the question - [Get selected element's outer HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html)

The code above writes all the radio button html into an array but you could change it to do what you wished within the loop.